# Query previously attached and installed USB Pen drives

Tags: windows-7, usb, usb-storage

is there a way or a method to query the Volume ID of a previously attached usb pen drive?
To answer the question which USB drive has been attached to this computer?
Eventlog? Registry?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [USBDeview](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/usb_devices_view.html) to check what usb device was and is connected to the machine. It gives out details like :

1. Device name/description
2. Device type
3. Serial number (for mass storage devices)
4. The date/time that device was added, etc.

And its a freeware :)

Comment: Beat me to it! +1.

Comment: @Mehper C. Palavuzlar  :)

Comment: I saw USBDeview but I am looking for the Volume ID ... and it seems like this is not displayed

Comment: @server did you use it , as the site boasts of many other details which they have have not mentioned

Comment: jep, I got a serialnumber but not the volume id...